# Error en Laravel DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, carbon

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Cree un virtual host y al ingresar a la URL a veces me abre la pagina de laravel y otras me tira ese error de DateTime, como puedo solucionarlo?
Buscando encontre esto:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207195/laravel-server-wont-start-error-datetime-construct-failed-to-parse-tim

Hago el php artisan key:generate pero no pasa nada, lo que sigue abajo del post de cambiar el formato de las fechas $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '06-23-2014'); no entiendo donde habria que hacerlo, repito no programe nada todavia, a veces me carga la pagina de Laravel y otras me sale el error que comento.

Comment: Hola Shaz, se instalo la 5.4.36, ahi agregue un print del error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo parece indicar que es un error de Carbon (El paquete que maneja las fechas en Laravel) en su versión 1.24.1

Según sus creadores, ya fue corregido rápidamente en la versión 1.24.2:

https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/1184

Comment: Si el error daba ahi, la cuestion es que inserte todo en otra pc y funciona de 10, el problema se da en mi notebook, voy a tener que ver que pasa ahi